# What's the meaning of "Gets me every time"?

Tags: meaning, verbs

I've heard people say this several times, in response to a funny video they watched,

> Gets me every time.

This time I see this response the person put a laughing emoticon at the end. Does it mean it makes them laugh every time?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The phrase means that whatever it is engenders some strong emotion: here it will be laughter, but in other contexts it might be tears, surprise, or embarrassment.

Answer (score 4):

"(something) *gets me*" is a catch phrase, *everytime* is an intensifier that suggests 'I can never get used to it'.

Eric Partridge in *A Dictionary of Catch Phrases* explains *[that gets me](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=jKVNWvTe6RcC&pg=PA447&lpg=PA447&dq=%22gets%20me%22)!*

> **that gets me!** is recorded in HLM, 1922, as a 'picturesque' phrase. Meaning: 'That annoys me': recorded by the DAE for 1867; current in Britain c. 1919-39. P.B.: but still current, in UK, by allusion, in remarks like 'What gets *me* about it is the way she can so blatantly...'
>   A.B., 1979, amplifies: 'Sometimes, *that really gets my goat!* [also Brit.] and [the later] *that really does piss me off*, which is often truncated to *I'm really P.O.'d!...* I don't think the "got" one is largely currently, but it isn't dead. ...

Loosely applied, the phrase could also mean *never fails to amuse me* or such.

Comment: It's a kind of shorthand for "It gets to me every time," whether what is "gotten to" is your funny bone, your tear ducts, your goat, or your suddenly reddening ears.